# SSH: What's the difference between -L and -R?

Tags: linux, ssh, port, port-forwarding, ssh-tunnel

I looked at the ssh manual (`man ssh`) and read the definitions for `-L` and `-R` option but don't quite understand the difference. Both seem capable of forwarding requests to a desired host and port. Can someone trying explaining the difference to a kid... What's the primary different between the two options?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's right there, in the man page:

> -L
> Specifies that connections to the given TCP port or Unix socket on the **local** (client) host are to be forwarded to the given host and port, or Unix socket, on the **remote** side.
>
> -R
> Specifies that connections to the given TCP port or Unix socket on the **remote** (server) host are to be forwarded to the **local** side.

<sub>(highlighting by me)</sub>

The difference is the direction. `-L` forwards local to remote, `-R` the reverse.